# OS Error when trying to read in a CSV file into a Jupyter notebook

Tags: csv, jupyter-notebook, jupyter

I'm trying to read in a fairly small csv file into a jupyter notebook but I keep getting an OSError.

This is my code:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import os
from pandas import Series, DataFrame

cars = pd.read_csv('‪C:/Data/mtcars.csv')
```

I am getting this error:

```
OSError                                   Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[29], line 1
----> 1 cars = pd.read_csv('‪C:/Data/mtcars.csv')
```

Any advice/help would be much appreciated.